# Hadoop Streaming can't run python

Tags: python, python-3.x, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

i am trying to execute hadoop streaming with mapreduce using python code however, it's always giving the same error result,

`File: file:/C:/py-hadoop/map.py is not readable`

or

`Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1`

im using **hadoop 3.1.1** and **python 3.8**, with **Windows 10** os

here's my map reduce command line

```
hadoop jar C:/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-3.1.1.jar -file C:/py-hadoop/map.py,C:/py-hadoop/reduce.py -mapper "python map.py" -reducer "python reduce.py" -input /user/input -output /user/python-output
```

map.py

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        print ("%s\t%s" % (word, 1))
```

reduce.py

```
from operator import itemgetter
import sys

current_word = None
current_count = 0
word = None
clean = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ '

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    word, count = line.split('\t', 1)
    try:
        count = int(count)
    except ValueError:
        continue
    word = filter(lambda x: x in clean, word).lower()
    if current_word == word:
        current_count += count
    else:
        if current_word:
            print ("%s\t%s" % (current_word, current_count))
        current_count = count
        current_word = word

if current_word == word:
    print ("%s\t%s" % (current_word, current_count))
```

also already tried with different command line, like

```
hadoop jar C:/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-3.1.1.jar -file C:/py-hadoop/map.py -mapper "python map.py" -file C:/py-hadoop/reduce.py -reducer "python reduce.py" -input /user/input -output /user/python-output
```

and

```
hadoop jar C:/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-3.1.1.jar -file py-hadoop/map.py -mapper "python map.py" -file py-hadoop/reduce.py -reducer "python reduce.py" -input /user/input -output /user/python-output
```

but still giving the exact same error result,

im sorry if my english is bad, im not a native speaker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

already fixed it,
the problem is caused by reduce.py, here's my new reduce.py

```
import sys
import collections

counter = collections.Counter()

for line in sys.stdin:
    word, count = line.strip().split("\t", 1)

    counter[word] += int(count)

for x in counter.most_common(9999):
    print(x[0],"\t",x[1])
```

and here is the command line that i used to run

```
hadoop jar C:/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-3.1.1.jar -file C:/py-hadoop/map.py -file C:/py-hadoop/reduce.py -mapper "python map.py" -reducer "python reduce.py" -input /user/input -output /user/python-output
```